# Filter object by empty properties/entries

Tags: javascript, object, filter

how can I filter an object like:

```
{"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar","driving":"","overnight":""}
```

to

```
{"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"}
```

remove only the empty key/value pairs

Comment: Go for some basics first :)https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: you want search based on key or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with Object.keys() and Array.prototype.forEach():

```
var original = {"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar","driving":"","overnight":""};
var filtered = {}
Object.keys(original).forEach(function(key) {
    if (original[key] !== "") {
        filtered[key] = original[key];
    }
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === '') {
        delete obj[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this . This code deletes keys **test** and **driving**

```
var obj = {"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar","driving":"","overnight":"", "test": null};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!obj[k] || obj[k] === "") {
        delete obj[k];
    }
});
console.log(obj);
```